# Background image is not working in Android Studio. (tried all previous solutions given on StackOverflow)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am making an coffee ordering app in which i want to put a background image covering the whole screen completely.(Note:The images are present in the drawable folder put by me from the google).

I tried to put background image using the layout `android:background="@drawable/cof"` but it's not working. It is showing this error:

[image]

I even tried putting different images in it but it is not working and showing the following error.

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cof"

    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="QUANTITY"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        />
     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:onClick="decrement"/>
         <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="18sp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
             android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
             android:text="2"
             />
         <Button
             android:layout_width="48dp"
             android:layout_height="48dp"
             android:text="+"
             android:onClick="increment"
             />

     </LinearLayout>

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="25sp"
         android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
         android:text="Price"
         android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Rs 10"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:text="ORDER"
        android:onClick="submitOrder"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please, provide a text of error and the file "cof".

Comment: sorry forgot to attach the scrrenshot.ok no problem i'll give u the error which comes on the 'preview screen' : Rendering problem-Could not resolve resourse "@drawable/cof".Failed to convert @drawable/cof into a drawable" - this is the message that comes on preview screen. what is the mistake. let me know what i can do to get my work done

Comment: i even tried restarting the android studio(invalidate catcher/restart) but still it is not working and giving me the same message on preview screen .What shall i do now? help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/drawable` folder can only have one of the following type of resoruces :

> "Bitmap files (.png, .9.png, .jpg, .gif) or XML files that are
>   compiled into the following drawable resource subtypes: : `Bitmap
>   files - Nine-Patches (re-sizable bitmaps) - State lists - Shapes -
>   Animation drawables - Other drawables -` "

Answer (score 1):

Drawable can't be html files.

Please refer to drawable [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html).

If you want to put an image only .png, .jpg, or .gif are accepted !

If you want to show a HTML page then you have to use a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

Comment: @Ayush Is it useful ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the file named "cof" is a drawable resource. It should be .png file or it should be .xml file. If it is a png file, try saving it again as a png image using your MS paint or Photoshop, sometimes when you rename or change the image extension cause problem in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set .htm or .html file as a background if you want to show html files you have to use WebView and by overlapping other views on WebView you can see it as background.

Answer (score 0):

I am also a beginner to android but i think this basically it happens when you did not use image with proper format. You should use .png format. In my opinion the code is correct to load the Background Image.